# Flutter _InternalLinkedHashMap error on model

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter I am getting error while conversing my response to model.

Error `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

My code:

```
        var map = json.decode(data);
        MatchData dd = MatchData.fromJson(map['data']);
        print(dd);
```

In response I am getting object but don't get why this error Is coming.

[image]

Comment: can you show model code and API response.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `map["data"]` is a type of `<String, dynamic>`.
The error says that you are parsing string to a type of `<String, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you are getting, it seems like `map['data']` is of type `String`.

You need to convert it to JSON format `Map<STring,dynamic>` before passing it to `MatchData.fromJson()`

Answer (score 0):

`MatchData.fromJson` requires a `String`. It might work to do:

```
    MatchData dd = MatchData.fromJson(json.encode(map['data']));
```

But good chance that your `MatchData` class also has a `fromMap` method. Then you can use

```
    MatchData dd = MatchData.fromMap(map['data']);
```